Disable Super+S
I've got a new Ubuntu 22.04/MATE install and have a simple requirement that I've been struggling with for days.  I want the Super+S (sometimes referred to as Mod4+s, Left Win, etc) keybinding to be "passed through" to the application.  Instead something at the "OS level" seems to be capturing it.  I've Googled and AI'ed exhaustively and find all kinds of hints and similar issues, but nothing that solves my problem - gsettings, gnome-tweaks, Expo, CompizConfig, etc.
In the end, I want my applications (in my case 99% VS Code), to "see" that Super+S has been hit and to process the action defined in VSC's keybindings.json.  VSC successfully works with any other keybinding I've tried - Super+W, for example, but literally any other Super+.  But, when I use the VSC keybinding wizard, the Super+S is recognized simply as 'meta', which is I believe VSC's synonym for 'Super'.
I believe this xev output is helpful, but I'm not sure how to interpret it.  I've added some # comments to the output.
# Here I press Super+w just as an example of what works.
# I believe the four KeyXXX events are Super down, w down,
# w up, Super up.  This seems logical and at what *I* expect.

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001,
    root 0x795, subw 0x0, time 622376, (-1215,262), root:(558,481),
    state 0x0, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001,
    root 0x795, subw 0x0, time 622756, (-1215,262), root:(558,481),
    state 0x40, keycode 25 (keysym 0x77, w), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (77) "w"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (77) "w"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001,
    root 0x795, subw 0x0, time 622860, (-1215,262), root:(558,481),
    state 0x40, keycode 25 (keysym 0x77, w), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (77) "w"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001,
    root 0x795, subw 0x0, time 622980, (-1215,262), root:(558,481),
    state 0x40, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,a
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False



# Here's Super+s.  We see the same Super down at the beginning
# and Super up at the end, but the stuff in between is
# baffling.  I assume it is the root of my problem and
# indicating that the Super+s has been captured and 
# processed by *something* and won't be passed 
# through to the app.

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001,
    root 0x795, subw 0x0, time 625724, (-1215,262), root:(558,481),
    state 0x0, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

FocusOut event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967189 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
           32  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001,
    root 0x795, subw 0x0, time 626144, (-1215,262), root:(558,481),
    state 0x40, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

Can anyone help me identify and resolve this problem?

First, create a keybinding in your Settings -> Keyboard -> View and Customize Shortcuts. Create a new custom shortcut like below. You will get a warning that "Super + S is already used" but ignore that and add the shortcut.

In the above example, the Super + S shortcut is replaced by a notify-send command which will show me that the new shortcut is triggered instead of the previous one.

Now, remove the shortcut from the custom shortcut and check whether any shortcut is working on it. In my case, it did nothing. By following this method, I think the shortcut in your VS code keybinding.json will start working.

Good workaround - actually not a workaround, because this way you effectively succeeded in disabling the default keybinding. This could be done directly in the dconf settings of mate, but I do not use mate so I could not search where the keybinding is assigned by default.

feel free to remove the 1st sentence :) @ajay

@ajay - Thanks so much for the idea.  I'd have never thought of approaching it this way!  But... no joy.
I run gnome-control-center and add a Custom Shortcut for Super+S exactly as you describe.  Except I am never alerted that it is already used.  And, afterwords, Super+S fails to run notify-send.  In any case, I go ahead and remove it and try the VSC keybinding with the same results as always.  :(
